# aasdk library building

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install this library for openauto and I faced this error during the build this library can anyone help me?

```
In file included from /home/abdelrahman/aasdk/include/f1x/aasdk/IO/PromiseLink.hpp:24,
                 from /home/abdelrahman/aasdk/src/Channel/Control/ControlServiceChannel.cpp:22:
/home/abdelrahman/aasdk/include/f1x/aasdk/IO/Promise.hpp:35:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
   35 | {
      | ^
/home/abdelrahman/aasdk/include/f1x/aasdk/IO/Promise.hpp:117:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
  117 | {
      | ^
/home/abdelrahman/aasdk/include/f1x/aasdk/IO/Promise.hpp:198:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
  198 | {
      | ^
/home/abdelrahman/aasdk/include/f1x/aasdk/IO/Promise.hpp:278:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
  278 | {
      | ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/aasdk.dir/build.make:154: CMakeFiles/aasdk.dir/src/Channel/Control/ControlServiceChannel.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/aasdk.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant details - your Ubuntu version, how you obtained the source code, and the commands you used to configure and build

Comment: iam using ubuntu 20 , i obtained the source code from aasdk repo on github

Comment: OK so I think the issue is just that the code (about 6 years old) was written for an earlier version of boost - in particular, the classes in `include/f1x/aasdk/IO/Promise.hpp` try to inherit from `boost::noncopyable` which does not appear to be exposed. You can try changing the base class to `boost::asio::noncopyable` but I suspect you will find other incompatibilites.