# openauto building error

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I have built aasdk library successfully the output was this

```
 abdelrahman@ubuntu:~/Desktop/aasdk/build$ make
[ 81%] Built target aasdk_proto
[100%] Built target aasdk
abdelrahman@ubuntu:~/Desktop/aasdk/build$ sudo cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
[sudo] password for abdelrahman: 
-- Install configuration: ""
```

But during building the openauto project it gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a programming question for StackOverflow because `fix/aasdk` looks like a path to a this specific piece of code that you are compling

Comment: You might want to revisit your previous question [aasdk library building](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503530/aasdk-library-building) and post your own answer explaining exactly how you succeeded in building aasdk.

Comment: As @DanielT says, if this was your code, then you should ask StackOverflow since this is a programming question.  But if this is written by someone else, then you need to ask them -- i.e., the developers of OpenAuto.  Their `CMakeLists.txt` file is supposed to find dependencies for you and it is not doing that.  The compiler cannot find `Promise.hpp`; ideally, `cmake` should have been written to try to find `aasdk` for you.  If you have it, you can try to hack it by putting it in the location that it is asking for (`fix/aasdk/IO/`) but you might have other errors later.